# Why do I have 100 Percent Disk usage Yet I'm barely running anything strenuous? (Windows 8)

Tags: windows-8

So this just recently started happening again. It's happened before but I somehow fixed it, not entirely sure how I once did. The problem also occurs in smart mode. In addition to that, there's a strange clicking sound coming from inside the computer, almost like a turning signal. I've checked the task manager and nothing seems to be making it do this. Sometimes it'll stop making the noise and the computer will act completely normal for a minute or two. Is something in my computer broken? What could be the problem guys?

Answer (score 3):

Clicks are baaad! If the click sounds like [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iWR34wKBNS0), or [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:WD_bad_heads_click_of_death.ogg),  your hard drive is dead or dying. There is a reason why it is known by the ominous name of [Click of Death](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Click_of_death#Hard_disk_drives).

In any case having such high I/O rates when not doing anything strenuous is a very bad sign. Backup your data *immediately* and buy a new hard drive.

As a general rule, if your computer is making strange mechanical sounding noises, something is seriously wrong. Not always, but often.

Comment: Yeah That's basically the same noise but a ton slower. It only makes the sound about twice then stops.

Comment: @NickH bad bad bad. The video and sound file I linked to are of extreme cases. They probably started our like yours. If your drive is still working backup NOW. It might stop working at any moment.

Answer (score 1):

That ticking sound could be faulty HDD or in a lot of cases it’s simply a wire slightly touching spinning fans. Also are you meaning by “100% usage” the HDD is full?

Comment: By 100% I mean in the task manager it says under the performance tab disk is at 100% percent.

Comment: That's CPU loading yeah, you need to sort it by image name to see what is using it the most...

Comment: I have about 387 GB free if that's what you mean. (Sorry, not exactly good with computers.)

Comment: You’re going back to HDD space now  ;)

Comment: I think he means I/O operations, isn't that what the "disk tab" is?

Comment: How about a screenshot?

Comment: http://gyazo.com/5de872299ef9d143f017e76dafd2f736

Comment: Also I don't think its the wire hitting a fan because it always ticks exactly when it shoots up to 100%

Comment: open "Resource Monitor" and look inside the Disk column which processes cause a lot of disk IO.